# Bitmap not large enough to support new configuration

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a Bitmap and i want to configure it. I also set my bitmap to Mutable one that's not a problem but when i want to configure, it comes with a error that **my bitmap is not large enough**.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.ic_cm);
bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
bitmap.setWidth(getWidth() / 2);
```

Comment: is it "buffer" size not large enough?

Comment: @navylover how do i now its buffer size..? I debug it but i didn't see any buffer size

Comment: Try replace Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 with bitmap.getConfig()

Comment: @navylover not worked